# Is there a no-foreach solution to merge alternating elements of two arrays into a string?

Tags: php, arrays

I can't figure out a nice (better than foreach) way to do this:

```
$arr  = ['blue', 'red', 'green', 'brown', 'yellow'];
$glue = ["\t","\t","\n",'-'];

echo mergeImplode($glue, $arr);  // blue\tred\tgreen\nbrown-yellow
```

Comment: array_map, but even that will be using a loop internally. don't be afraid of the loop. embrace the loop.

Comment: @MarcB, I just care for clean code, no more.  Thanks, I figured out the way with array_map, I will try

Comment: How is a foreach not "clean code" ? The loop is inevitable, no matter how much layer of code you put, there shall be a loop somewhere.

Comment: is not clean if besides the foreach it is necesary ifs, flags or whatever, care about first, or last, etc, to complete the task

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways on how to do that. I like `array_reduce` and thats why I use it :)

```
$arr  = ['blue', 'red', 'green', 'brown', 'yellow'];
$glue = ["\t","\t","\n",'-'];
array_reduce ( $arr, function($carry, $item) use (&$glue){
    $gl = array_pop($glue);
    return ($gl ? $gl : '') . $item . $carry;
}, '' ] )
```